# OAuth Dribbble with Firebase Functions gives 'invalid_grant' error constantly

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently trying to OAuth with Dribbble. I'm using Angular 4 with Firebase Functions/Google Cloud Functions as a backend. I've tried various different methods, spent over 12 hours on this and nothing seems to be working for me. I'm not very experienced with OAuthing, so I can't tell if this is an issue with the API or an issue with the way I'm doing things. Am I supposed to do the initial redirection to the auth url (the first step basically on every OAuth documentation) with my server or with my client? I've seen both done and neither works for me.

Here's the details:

According to Dribbble docs (http://developer.dribbble.com/v2/oauth/), the first step is to "Redirect users to request Dribbble access."

```
GET https://dribbble.com/oauth/authorize
```

The first thing I've tried is to directly send users to that url through my client. On Angular it looks something like this:

```
window.location.href = https://dribbble.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=clientidhere&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/signup?step=three&state=230948lksdjf02384ldskf
```

I then need to make a POST request to Dribbble get the access_token with the code Dribbble sends back to me in their redirection. I can't do this client-side because of CORS issues, so I call an endpoint on my firebase function which makes the POST request. My function http trigger looks something like `https://us-central1-my-test-app.cloudfunctions.net/oAuthUserLink?state=20384jksdf0238&code=koij3o4u0s9df8234jlsdkjf093284`

It will then call this function:

```
exports.oAuthUserLink = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    return getAuthToken(req, res, admin, config, otherConfig);
  });
});

getAuthToken = function (req, res, admin, fbConfig, config) {
  const rp = require('request-promise');

  const oAuthUrl = 'https://dribbble.com/oauth/token?';
  const code = '&code=' + req.query.code;
  let state = '&state=' + req.query.state;     
  const clientId = '?client_id=' + config.dribbble.client_id;
  const secret = '&client_secret=' + config.dribbble.client_secret;

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: oAuthUrl + clientId + secret + code + state,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  };

  rp(options)
  .then(body => {
    const bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log('bodyObj', bodyObj)
  });

}
```

This returns me with a very generic error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."
}
```

So this obviously doesn't work, no matter where I do it, when I do it, how often I do it. I thought maybe there's an issue with the fact that my client is calling that initial URL whereas my functions are handling the exchanging of the code for the access_token.

So next, I try to make a redirect function inside my Firebase Functions so that could redirect users to request authorization from their account. This way, both calls are coming from my firebase functions and the redirection url could be my firebase function's http trigger. It looks something like this:

```
exports.redirect = function (req, res, admin) {
  const config = functions.config();  
  const rp = require('request-promise');

  const state = req.query.state;
  const userId= req.query.userId;
  const redirectUrl = `https://us-central1-my-test-app.cloudfunctions.net/oAuthUserLink`; 
  //here I've changed the redirectUrl from localhost to the endpoint to my function above
  const clientId = config.dribbble.client_id;

    const getToken = {
      uri: `https://dribbble.com/oauth/authorize`,
      qs: {
        client_id: clientId,
        state: state,
        redirect_uri: redirectUrl
      },
      headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Needly Workcoin Market'}
    };

  rp(getToken).then(response => {
    res.send(response); //this response is a 302 redirect to their login page
  });
}
```

This redirects me to a login page for Dribbble, it but looks different from the first method I tried above (there's no Authorize button, you just log in). After I press log in, it redirects me to `https://us-central1-my-test-app.cloudfunctions.net/session` with a 403 error. I have no idea why it redirects me there upon login because nowhere in my redirect url in the initial GET did I put this 'session' thing in there.

I've double checked and triple checked all my credentials and params I'm sending in to them. Could someone with some experience with Oauth give me some guidance on which way is the right way to do things with Firebase Functions, and perhaps shed some light on why nothing works for me here?

Comment: An additional note: I did my first method with Github Oauth and it works perfectly. I did both methods with Medium and neither methods work (the authorization url always leads me to a 400 error).